# RADGridView Start with Column Sorted

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

How would I set a Grid Column to be sorted at startup?  I cannot seem to find a property on the RadGridView to tell it that I want Column one sorted Descending at startup.  The grid just comes up with no sorting.

Answer (score 13):

You can also do it declaratively:

```
 <tk:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourDataSource}" >
   <tk:RadGridView.SortDescriptors>
        <tk:SortDescriptor Member="Email" SortDirection="Ascending" />
    </tk:RadGridView.SortDescriptors>
    <tk:RadGridView.Columns>
        <tk:GridViewDataColumn Header="Account" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Email}" />
    </tk:RadGridView.Columns>
 </tk:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a sort descriptor to the SortDescriptors collection.

For Example:

radGridView1.SortDescriptors.Add(new Telerik.WinControls.Data.SortDescriptor("Email", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

"Email" -  is the column you want to sort on.